# Is the adjugate matrix unique?

Tags: matrices

Given a matrix $A$, is $\text{adj}(A)$ always the same regardless of the ring or field it is defined over?

For instance, let $A_R$ be an $n \times n$ matrix over real numbers with integer entries, and let $A_{20}$ be a matrix with the same entries as $A_R$ but defined over $\mathbb{Z}_{20}$. Assuming that $A_{20}$ is an invertible matrix, can we say $\text{adj}(A_R)$ = $\text{adj}(A_{20})$?

I have looked at a few small examples and in all cases they are equal. But I'd like to make sure that it is true in general. If it is, could you please provide a proof or a simple justification?

Comment: Please insert your definition of adjoint matrix

Comment: The transpose of the cofactor matrix. 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjugate_matrix

Comment: even if it is not invertible, the adj is just the projection

Comment: What would it even mean to say that some integer equals an element of ${\Bbb Z}_{20}$?

Comment: @JamieRadcliffe For example, if the element $(1,1)$ of $A_R = 2$ then the element $(1,1)$ of  $A_{20} = 2$. I do not mean to say $2$ over real numbers is the same as $2$ over $\mathbb{Z}_{20}$.

Comment: And what if over $\Bbb Z$ it's 40 and over ${\Bbb Z}_{20}$ it's $[0]$? Are they the same? And if it's $[3]$ in ${\Bbb Z}_{13}$ and $[5]$ in ${\Bbb Z}_{19}$. Are they the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, an element in $A^{m\times m}$ can not be equal to an element in $R^{m\times m}$ if $A$ and $R$ are different abstract rings. Now if $A$ and $R$ are somehow comparable, then the previous statement starts to make sense:

In your case, I believe you are trying to compare the rings $\mathbb{Z}^{m\times m}$ and $\mathbb{Z}_n^{m\times m}$ via de canonical quotient $\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}_n$. This map induces a quotient $\phi_n:\mathbb{Z}^{m \times m}\to \mathbb{Z}_n^{m\times m}$. In this setting, the question "is $adj(A)$ always the same?" corresponds to "does $\phi_n(adj(A))$ equal to $adj(\phi_n(A))$"?

Now the operation $A\mapsto adj(A)$ is a combination of sums and products of the entries of $A$ which does not depend on the base ring. Therefore the equality
$$adj(\phi_n(A))=\phi_n(adj(A)) $$
holds (I suggest that you prove this statement with the corresponding calculation yourself - and conclude that the answer to your question is """yes""").

As for the "regardless of the ring.." statement: if $f: \mathbb{Z}\to R$ is any ring homomorphism (for example, the inclusion $\mathbb{Z}\hookrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{Z}\hookrightarrow \mathbb{Q}[i]$), then by the same argument the induced map $\overline{f}:\mathbb{Z}^{m\times m}\to R^{m\times m}$ satisfies
$$adj(\overline{f}(A))=\overline{f}(adj(A)) $$
for every $A\in \mathbb{Z}^{m\times m}$.

Comment: +1, but also OP talks about "regardless of the ring or field it is defined over".

Comment: True, @JamieRadcliffe. I added a sentence regarding this.